# Django Error Message From django.db Models To Admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-admin

I'm using DRF to create an API backend. Now, I want to enforce certain validation rules while saving the models from the admin. I'm using `viewset` and can override when called from the rest framework. But when I validate model by overriding the `save()` method, it can't send any error message to the admin as it doesn't have any `request` parameter. The scenario is like this:

```
from django.db import models

class PatientCaregiver(models.Model):    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do some processing
        # return some error or success msg(how?)
```

I know that I can send the error message with the following code:

```
from django.contrib import messages
messages.error(request,'Error message')
```

But as you can see, in my **save()**  model, I don't have the request parameter. So, how to send any error message from the **save()** model to the admin?

Comment: but why you need that error message in the model save method ?

Comment: because that's where the request reaches when executed from the django admin. i think i can't use views to deal with admin actions. can i?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to deal with this is to raise an exception within the `save`, catch it in the view and add your message code there.

Comment: but how do i overrride admin action in the views? i don't know if there is a way.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#admin-custom-validation